# how can we show/hide div tags using value of radio buttons in jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hi i am very new to jquery and i am working on show and hide div tags using values of radio buttons. here is my HTML.

```html
<div id="OwnVehicle" style="display:none">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="vehicleList" id="two" onclick="fuelList()" value="1" />Two Wheeler
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="vehicleList" id="four" onclick="fuelList()" value="2" />Four Wheeler
  </label>
</div>



<div id="TwoWheeler" style="display:none">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="TwoWheeler" value="6" />Electric
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="TwoWheeler" value="7" />Petrol
  </label>
</div>
<div id="FourWheeler" style="display:none">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="FourWheeler" value="1" />Electric
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="FourWheeler" value="2" />Petrol
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="FourWheeler" value="3" />Diesel
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="FourWheeler" value="4" />CNG
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="FourWheeler" value="5" />LPG
  </label>
</div>
```

now i need help in writing a jquery code for showing the div tag with id = "two wheeler" when radio button value = 1 and div tag with id = "four wheeler" when radio button value = 2.

thnaks in advance.

sorry for anyone who couldnt understand my question.

Comment: I think you want to check out the jQuery functions `change()` and `show()`/`hide()`

Comment: You're so new to jQuery you don't appear to have written any...

Comment: Could you please respond to the answer so that i can know it is working for you or if you need any changes let know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

```js
function fuelList(val) {
  var val = parseInt(val);
  if (val == 1) {
    $('#FourWheeler').hide();
    $('#TwoWheeler').show();
  } else {
    $('#TwoWheeler').hide();
    $('#FourWheeler').show();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="OwnVehicle">
  <label>
     <input type="radio" name="vehicleList" id="two" onclick="fuelList(this.value)" value="1" />Two Wheeler
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="vehicleList" id="four" onclick="fuelList(this.value)" value="2" />Four Wheeler
  </label>
</div>

<div id="TwoWheeler" style="display:none">
  <label>
      <input type="radio" name="TwoWheeler" value="6" />Electric
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="TwoWheeler" value="7" />Petrol
  </label>
</div>
<div id="FourWheeler" style="display:none">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="FourWheeler" value="1" />Electric
  </label>
  <label>
      <input type="radio" name="FourWheeler" value="2" />Petrol
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="FourWheeler" value="3" />Diesel
  </label>
  <label>
     <input type="radio" name="FourWheeler" value="4" />CNG
  </label>
  <label>
     <input type="radio" name="FourWheeler" value="5" />LPG
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Why `parseInt`?

Comment: sometime its take as a string value so it will convert string to intger and compare

Comment: You have assigned the value as 1 in your HTML. Its not a user-input. Why do you need that additional check. Its easily avoidable.

Comment: if you can setisfy with this answer so give as a accepted answer so it will display first and see easily for all @hemanthmangalampalli

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do easily with JQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("input[name='vehicleList']").click(function(){
   var selectedValue = $(this).val();
   if(selectedValue === "1"){
      $('#TwoWheeler').show();
      $('#FourWheeler').hide();
   }else{
      $('#TwoWheeler').hide();
      $('#FourWheeler').show();
   }
 });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="OwnVehicle">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="vehicleList" id="two" value="1" />Two Wheeler
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="vehicleList" id="four"  value="2" />Four Wheeler
                        </label>
</div>



<div id="TwoWheeler" style="display:none">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="TwoWheeler" value="6" />Electric
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="TwoWheeler" value="7" />Petrol
                        </label>
</div>
<div id="FourWheeler" style="display:none">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="FourWheeler" value="1" />Electric
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="FourWheeler" value="2" />Petrol
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="FourWheeler" value="3" />Diesel
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="FourWheeler" value="4" />CNG
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="FourWheeler" value="5" />LPG
                        </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion is to change your onclick="" to onchange="".

```
<input type="radio" name="vehicleList" id="four" onchange="fuelList(this)" value="2"  class="radioButtons" />Four Wheeler

<script>
 function fuelList(element)
{
   var id = element.value;
   if( id == 1)
     {
      $(".wheels")hide(); //hides all the elements with class = wheels
      $("#twoWheelers")show(); //shows the div with id = twoWheelers
     }
    else if( id == 2 )
     {
      $(".wheels")hide(); //hides all the elements with class = wheels
      $("#fourWheelers")show(); //shows the div with id = fourWheelers
      }
}
</script>
```

and put a class to the div of your "twoWheeler" and "fourWheeler"
I just make it "wheels"

```
 <div id="twoWheelers" class="wheels">
 ...
 </div>

 <div id="fourWheelers" class="wheels">
 ...
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yiu can try this working code:

```js
function fuelList(_this){
  var value=$(_this).attr("value");
  
  $("#TwoWheeler").hide();
  $("#FourWheeler").hide();
  
  if(value=="1"){
    $("#TwoWheeler").show();
  }
  else  if(value=="2"){
    $("#FourWheeler").show();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="OwnVehicle">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="vehicleList" id="two" onclick="fuelList(this)" value="1" />Two Wheeler
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="vehicleList" id="four" onclick="fuelList(this)" value="2" />Four Wheeler
                        </label>
                    </div>


<div id="TwoWheeler" style="display:none">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="TwoWheeler" value="6" />Electric
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="TwoWheeler" value="7" />Petrol
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div id="FourWheeler" style="display:none">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="FourWheeler" value="1" />Electric
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="FourWheeler" value="2" />Petrol
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="FourWheeler" value="3" />Diesel
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="FourWheeler" value="4" />CNG
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="FourWheeler" value="5" />LPG
                        </label>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understood the question correctly, and you want to hide a div when you check a radio button?

Here is an example of how that can be achieved:

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="euResident" id="euResidentYes" value="Yes" checked />
<label for="euResidentYes" class="radio">yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="euResident" id="euResidentNo" value="No" />
<label for="euResidentNo" class="radio">no</label>

<div id='div'>Hello World</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function switchVar() {
    if($("#euResidentNo").prop("checked"))
        $("#div").show();
     else
        $("#div").hide();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    switchVar();
    $("input[name=euResident]").change(switchVar);
});
```

It is an example using Javascript as this is perfect to use for this.
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2Uj9F/169/

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ym10add9/

```
$("input[type='radio']").change(function() {
    $('div').hide();
    $( '#' + $(this).attr('value')).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote code as per you describe in your post. May be useful to solve your problem.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=radio][name=vehicleList]').change(function() {
        if (this.value == '1') {
            $("#FourWheeler").hide();
    $("#TwoWheeler").show();
        }
        else if (this.value == '2') {
            $("#FourWheeler").show();
            $("#TwoWheeler").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="vehicleList">
 <label>
    <input type="radio" name="vehicleList" id="two" value="1" />Two Wheeler
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="vehicleList" id="four" value="2" />Four Wheeler
  </label> 
</div>

<h5>Output : </h5>
<div id="TwoWheeler" style="display:none">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="TwoWheeler" value="6" />Electric
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="TwoWheeler" value="7" />Petrol
  </label>
</div>
<div id="FourWheeler" style="display:none">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="FourWheeler" value="1" />Electric
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="FourWheeler" value="2" />Petrol
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="FourWheeler" value="3" />Diesel
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="FourWheeler" value="4" />CNG
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="FourWheeler" value="5" />LPG
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is simple JQuery code that will help you to achieve your requirement:

```js
$("input[name='vehicleList']").on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 1) {
    $('#TwoWheeler').show();
    $('#FourWheeler').hide();
  } else {
    $('#TwoWheeler').hide();
    $('#FourWheeler').show();
  }
});
```

```css
#TwoWheeler,
#FourWheeler {
  display: none;
}

#OwnVehicle label,
#TwoWheeler label,
#FourWheeler label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="OwnVehicle">
  <label>
        <input type="radio" name="vehicleList" id="two" value="1" />Two Wheeler
    </label>
  <label>
        <input type="radio" name="vehicleList" id="four" value="2" />Four Wheeler
    </label>
</div>

<div id="TwoWheeler">
  <label>
        <input type="radio" name="TwoWheeler" value="6" />Electric
    </label>
  <label>
        <input type="radio" name="TwoWheeler" value="7" />Petrol
    </label>
</div>
<div id="FourWheeler">
  <label>
        <input type="radio" name="FourWheeler" value="1" />Electric
    </label>
  <label>
        <input type="radio" name="FourWheeler" value="2" />Petrol
    </label>
  <label>
        <input type="radio" name="FourWheeler" value="3" />Diesel
    </label>
  <label>
        <input type="radio" name="FourWheeler" value="4" />CNG
    </label>
  <label>
        <input type="radio" name="FourWheeler" value="5" />LPG
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

This is one way to do it:

```
$( "#r0" ).bind( "click", function() {
  $("#OwnVehicle").show();
  $("#TwoWheeler").hide();
});

$( "#r1" ).bind( "click", function() {
  $("#OwnVehicle").hide();
  $("#TwoWheeler").show();
});
```

Here a working fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/0aa8w2sj/

It can be improved

Comment: Why do we need to have two id to bind separately?

Comment: You could put your radio's in a div and use jquery selector to get all the radio input in this div, that's another way to do is.

I juste gave the most straightforward way :)